# Chrome is ignoring my font choice

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I'm having a little difficulty getting Chrome to recognise my font-choice. I've not got a lot of code as I've only just started this website.

Basically I have a `reset.css` on the website and then my `main.css` is called afterwards. In the `reset.css` it declares the below statement under pretty much every html tag under the sun:

```
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
```

In the main.css the same statement is declared under `html`, `body` and `p`, and even some specific `p` tags such as `p.headerText` and `p.newsDate`

This is a pretty standard setup. On Safari, IE and Firefox, the font renders as Arial / Helvetica, on Chrome it renders as Times New Roman.

It's really frustrating. Can anybody help?

**UPDATE**

The Computed Style on Chrome is showing the correct rule, and I even tested this on a friend of mines machine and it was the same. Both running Chrome 8.0.552.237 on OSX 10.6.6

Cheers

Comment: Have you double-checked the paths to your stylesheets are correct?

Comment: Working for me in Chrome. Renders Arial.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the error. Checking in firefox 3.6 and Chrome 9.0.597.86 beta both appear to use the correct fonts.

Comment: Looks fine to me - do you have a user defined style sheet?

Comment: Workds for me as well, try reloading cache.

Comment: This would all suggest that perhaps it's my browser settings and not the Chrome rendering engine, thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Cache reloading doesn't help. And my Under the Hood settings say that the default sans-serif font is Helvetica, so I still can't explain this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured out the problem. I'd used the `font-weight: lighter;` command - I removed this and the problem disappeared. This would suggest that it's a clash of fonts on my machine. Still don't understand why it appeared fine on everyone else's machine but the problem is now fixed - doesn't look right because I have to use a heavier font but it's still works.

**UPDATE**

We're a graphic design agency so there are thousands of font-variations on my machine. It seems the clash was there. I swapped Helvetica and Arial in the font-stack and it seems to be fine all round now.

Also, it seems to do with Chrome and Font Books that aren't the standard ones on a Mac. I did some hunting and I found a script that'll work, albeit temporarily.   http://www.danielhanly.com/blog/tutorial/google-chrome-for-mac-broken-fonts/
This will clear your internal font cache and will fix the problem for a short time.

Essentially, this isn't a problem with the code, but rather, a problem with my development machine. There's some clash of fonts happening when we manage our fonts with a non-standard font manager (Linotype FontExplorer). Strange that it's only in Chrome though.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same problem (only in Chrome) occurred to me!

But after **deactivation** of **font "Arial"** (no matter if truetype, postscript, opentype etc.) in my Mac SnowLeopard system, this effect of displaying Times New Roman instead a Sans Serif Font like Arial, Helvetica, Verdana etc. disappeared completely.

I hope it helps.

```
 Modellname:    iMac
  Modell-Identifizierung:   iMac10,1
  Prozessortyp: Intel Core 2 Duo
  Prozessorgeschwindigkeit: 3,06 GHz
  Anzahl der Prozessoren:   1
  Gesamtzahl der Kerne: 2
  L2-Cache: 3 MB
  Speicher: 4 GB
  Busgeschwindigkeit:   1,07 GHz
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to "Inspect element" with Chrome, and look at "computed style". What is it written?

Always inspecting styles, is your font-family overwritten?

#### Update

I tried for you. I see Arial, the right font. See attachment.
[image]

Comment: I have this as well... It's frustrating as it's only displaying Times New Roman. There has to be a clash somewhere but it's not making itself easy to find

Comment: If everyone's Chrome is showing Arial and yours is showing Times New Roman I guess it's a Chrome installation problem, not your website.

Comment: If Times New Roman because if you go to Chrome > Settings > Appearance > Customise fonts, you can see the fallback font is Times New roman. Not sure what's causing it though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a cache-less refresh? (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

It's possible that chrome is using an older, cached copy of the CSS.

Comment: Nope, no luck I'm afraid - I've also emptied the cache completely and still stuck with Times New Roman

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using bootstrap on a page.  It was the specification of `text-rendering: optimizelegibility;` that was causing the rendering problem of my font in Chrome.

I changed it to `text-rendering: auto;` and that seemed to fix the problem.